# Doctrine+MongoDB - How to query for documents with array that's not empty

Tags: php, doctrine-odm

I would like to receive all the documents with array "likes" with size greater than zero. I saw an example of using the ->size() method to get an array in a specific size:

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Article')->field('comments')->size(0);
```

but not to get an array with size different than zero, is there an option to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass specific positive integers to `size`, but you cannot use it to query ranges. This is not a limitation of Doctrine but of MongoDB. The docs on [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) say:

> $size does not accept ranges of values. To select documents based on
>   fields with different numbers of elements, create a counter field that
>   you increment when you add elements to a field.

To do this, add a `$comments_count` `@Int` field to Article and update it either a) in document methods which modify `$comments` or b) in a document method annotated with `@PreUpdate`.

Another (inefficient) option is to use `where` with a javascript expression:

```
$where = "function() { return this.comments && this.comments.length > 0; }";
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Article')->field('comments')->where($where);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript for this is really slow. You should prefer "pure" QueryBuilder:

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Article');
$qb = $qb->field('comments')
         ->exists(true)
         ->not($qb->expr()->size(0));
```